# How to save tmux session to tmuxinator project?

Tags: command-line, terminal, save, tmux, tmuxinator

I'm a tmux user and a fan of [tmuxinator](https://github.com/aziz/tmuxinator) because it lets me get back to a baseline tmux session setup with ease.

However, I find that my setup changes on a regular basis, and editing my tmuxinator setup by hand can become tedious.

Is there a way to effectively `tmuxinator save-session`, such that my *current* tmux session gets saved into a tmuxinator project of choice with the panes, windows, and other details of the session automatically stored?

Comment: Similar question on SU for reference: http://superuser.com/questions/440015/restore-tmux-session-after-reboot

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a tmux plugin I wrote that enables you to save and completely restore tmux sessions/environments:

https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect

Comment: tmux-ressurect and tmux-continum are both great, but I cannot figure out how to restore the command on each window. Is this possible?

Comment: OP here. tmux-resurrect is my current preferred solution to this problem. The other tmux-plugins are cool too!

Comment: The proposed plug-in is very limited as it cannot create tmuxinator files as OP asked for plausibly.

Answer (score 11):

I've been trying to figure out how to save sessions.  One solution I am looking at can be found here:

[Custom Scripts for saving Tmux sessions...](http://brainscraps.wikia.com/wiki/Resurrecting_tmux_Sessions_After_Reboot)

This link provides scripts that the author wrote for saving sessions at regular intervals, and saving a series of backups of those sessions.

I haven't personally tried the scripts myself, but they seem to be a potential issue for this situation.

(As for myself:  I'm a little surprised that Tmux doesn't provide something like this as a built-in feature.  With Screen I can understand:  the code base is so messy, it's difficult to add anything new...)

Answer (score 0):

**Steps:**

1. Clone the **tmux-resurrect** repository: Clone the tmux-resurrect repository to your local machine using git. Run the following command to clone the repository into the `~/.tmux/plugins` directory:

```
git clone https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect ~/.tmux/plugins/tmux-resurrect
```

2. Configure Tmux to use the plugin: Add the following line to your `~/.tmux.conf` file to enable the tmux-resurrect plugin:

```
run-shell ~/.tmux/plugins/tmux-resurrect/resurrect.tmux
```

3. Reload the Tmux configuration: Reload the Tmux configuration file by running the following command in the terminal:

`tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`

4. Prefix (ctl+b) + ctl+s to **save** and
   Prefix (ctl+b) + ctl+r to **restore**